# How can I view contacts that were on my now destroyed device

Tags: contacts, sync

My cell phone was destroyed. I tried to view my contacts info on my wife's LG but the list of contacts that I viewed were far from recent. I logged onto Google and found no help in reference to viewing my current list of contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Your only means of accessing your list of contacts is through your google account (which is how I assume you tried to do so with your wife's phone). However, this is dependent on when you last synced your contacts with your google account on your phone before it was destroyed. So, it's possible that you didn't make a recent sync back when it was still working. You can double-check your gmail account and look at your list of contacts there.

Answer (score 0):

Google is going to be your best bet. However, if you have a ton of contacts and getting that list back immediately is extremely important, I have two other suggestions:

1. I know that when I setup my phone it syncs with several accounts (including Samsung) in addition to Google. You may be able to get LG customer service to help you if they sync them too.
2. Your other option (if Google's customer support can't help) is to get a really cheap, used Android phone off from e-bay or something, and use it to re-sync them.

One last idea. I use a custom dialer app on my phone that syncs my contacts as well. If you had one installed, their customer support (find the dialer app in the Play Store) might be able to help as well.

I hope these ideas help. They're about the only options available to you.